# Dynamic Struct Array at Specific Address

Tags: c, pointers, struct, kernel

I am attempting to dynamically allocate an array of the following struct at a particular address in memory.  I use the pointer `struct page_frame* memBlocks` as the start to the array, but each access to the next element with `memBlocks[i]` in the for loop only moves 8 bytes.  I checked the size of my struct in gdb which shows the expected 16 bytes, so why are accesses to the pointer behaving in this way?

```
struct page_frame{
struct page_frame* next; //Next node of linked list
int used;

};

struct page_frame* memBlocks;

memBlocks = (struct page_frame*)0xffffffff80000000 + physFree;
int indices = ((int)physEnd/4096)


for(int i = 0; i < indices; i++)
{
    struct page_frame temp;
    temp.used = 3;
    temp.next = (struct page_frame*)&memBlocks[i+1];
    memBlocks[i] = temp;
}
```

Comment: You haven't given us enough information about your target architecture (x86, x64?, etc) and you haven't shown the type of memBlocks, but given the way you're using casts, I suspect that your cast operators need to be applied to expressions wrapped in parentheses. A cast operator binds very tightly. Is physFree in units of bytes, or page_frame's?

Comment: It looks like memBlocks is not declared as a struct page_frame variable.  So, it's likely that whatever type it is, is only 8 bytes in size.  So, when you index it as an array subscript, you'll only increment by the original size of the memBlocks variable, whatever it is.

Comment: You do not allocate anything, just wildly cast an integer to a pointer. This is undefined behaviour in the first place. As that seems to be a 64 bit value, I presume you have a full-grown OS. What makes you think that will work?

Comment: what is `physFree`?  Hopefully not a byte offset you're trying to apply.

Comment: The cast is redundant in `(struct page_frame*)&memBlocks[i+1];`  , the right-hand side already has that type.

Comment: It is for x86 architecture.  I just added the definition of memBlocks which is a pointer to struct page_frame.  physFree is in fact the byte offset which I want to have the array start at.  I am creating an array to keep track of physical memory in a kernel that I am designing.  I need to allocate the array at a known address so it can easily be found. How can I make the array start there and have each element contain a struct page_frame?

Comment: For the x86 architecture, 8 bytes seems right - 4 for the pointer, and 4 for the int (no padding). How are you seeing 16 bytes in gdb?

Comment: I apologize I'm using x86-64 but I meant that I am utilizing x86 hardware architecture.  Anyhow, there should thus be 8 bytes for my pointer and 8 for the int.  When I print sizeof(struct page_frame) this works correctly and it shows 16.  But from my loop where I am trying to dynamically allocate these structs it only stores the struct page_frame* next, and not the int of my struct.  Do you know how I can ensure all of the entire struct is in each element of this array?

Comment: this line: `temp.next = (struct page_frame*)&memBlocks[i+1];` incrementing the wrong thing.  suggest: `temp.next = memBlocks[i+1];`  however, a page is usually 4096 bytes, but the struct definition does not take that into account.  And no memory has been allocated for `memBlocks` to be pointing to an array of the struct.  So accessing unallocated memory is undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event

Comment: this kind of line: `memBlocks[i] = temp;` is very unlikely to copy the whole 'temp' struct,   Strongly suggest: `memcpy( &(memBlocks[i]), temp, sizeof( struct page_frame) );`

Comment: I added the kernel tag since people are assuming you're writing a normal, user-level app. It would have been helpful to include that hugely significant detail in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was overwriting my structs by setting each element equal to temp. I was able to fix it with the following.

```
struct page_frame* memBlocks = (struct page_frame*)0xffffffff80000000 + physFree;

int indices = ((int)physEnd/4096);
//struct page_frame arr[physEnd];


for(int i = 0; i < indices; i++)
{

    memBlocks[i].used = 1;
    memBlocks[i].next = &memBlocks[i+1];

}
```

Comment: this is still undefined behaviour as memBlocks, a pointer, is set to a value, but that value is not to allocated memory for an array of `struct page_frame` structs.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am however creating a physical page frame allocator though, so at this point there is no way to allocate memory. That's why I'm placing it at the specific address which is right at the end of my kernel. Also I don't want it the size of a 4KB page because I will be using the array to keep track of all physical 4KB pages so the structs must be smaller.